# Passing sed a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a bash script that uses sed and I am trying to a variable to $db, but $db has ` around it. This keeps me from being able to pass it the variable.

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `$db`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' $path$infile > $path$outfile.sql
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the sed script in double rather than single quotes, and use backslashes to escape the backticks:

```
sed -n "/^-- Current Database: \`${db}\`/,/^-- Current Database: \`/p" $path$infile > $path$outfile.sql
```